# Understanding git flow process

Tags: git, merge, git-flow

I just recently started using git flow but I am running into issue all the time. I believe I do not fully understand the process of merging a feature. I am running into merge conflicts all the time and getting errors that my `develop` and `origin/develop` have diverged. This is my process...

I want to make changes to develop, so I create a feature...

```
git flow feature start MYFEATURE
```

Now I am in feature `MYFEATURE` locally. So I make the changes I want and I `git add` then `git commit` then `git push` to my `MYFEATURE`.

Now I want to merge my feature to develop but in the meantime, other devs have pushed to develop branch so mine is not up to date. So to update it I do...

```
git pull origin develop
```

This gives me lots of conflicts, so I fix them and then I `git push`. At this point I try to merge my feature and I get more errors, my steps must be wrong.

Anyways then I do...

```
git flow feature finish MYFEATURE
```

and it tells me my local is ahead by x commits, so I do,

```
 git push
```

Can someone show me the right process of doing this, step-by-step? I think I am not entirely sure how this is working.

Comment: "try to merge my feature and I get more errors", can you attach the errors?

Comment: @sajibkhan for example it says `Your branch is ahead of 'origin/develop' by 12 commits.` after merging to develop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After pulling `develop` branch into `MYFEATURE`, push the changes to remote. Then checkout `develop` branch, pull `MYFEATURE` into `develop`, then push to remote.

```
$ git fetch
$ git checkout MYFEATURE
$ git pull origin develop
# fix conflicts if occur

$ git push origin MYFEATURE
# now remote/MYFEATURE has MYFEATURE + develop changes

# merge MYFEATURE with develop
$ git checkout develop
$ git pull origin develop
$ git pull origin MYFEATURE              # merge MYFEATURE branch
$ git push origin develop                
# push to remote, now develop has develop + MYFEATURE changes
```